# error in pg-pool module when using postgres module with nodejs and heroku

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

I am trying to use a postgresql database within nodejs server application hosted with Heroku.

This is my code for pg in app.js:

```
var pg = require('pg');
pg.defaults.ssl = true;
pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function(err, client) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Connected to postgres!');
});
```

and npm declaration file package.json:

```
{
  "name": "utility-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": 
  {
  "ejs": "*",
  "express": "3.3.x",
  "pg": "6.0.1",
  "simple-oauth2": "^0.7.0"
  },
  "engines": 
  {
  "node": "0.10.x",
  "npm": "1.2.x"
  }
}
```

This is working in my local environment but when i push the code to Heroku the server crashed:

[Screenshot of console demonstrating the crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5L49r.png)

Thank you for your help,

JP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pg-pool` is using an ES6 Promise, which isn't supported in the version of Node.js on your Heroku account, which is before 0.12.

You need to use a more modern version of Node.js, such as 4.x